# what is difference between [{type: String}] and {type: [String]} in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i was trying to get data such that if no value is assigned to field, it should not appear in the collection.

i tried this:

```
const CollectionSchema = new Schema({
  field1: [{ type: String, default: undefined}],
});

OR

const CollectionSchema = new Schema({
  field1: [{ type: String, default: () => undefined}],
});
```

which didn't worked, and whenever i tried to create it empty `field1:[]` showed up.

but then this code worked. what is the difference in two given snippets for creating nested array such that field is not shown when no data is added?

```
const CollectionSchema = new Schema({
  field1: { type: [String], default: () => undefined},
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `[{ type: String, default: undefined}]` you create an array as a `field1` which has string as an element. If there's no value, you will have undefined element in array. That is why it doesn't work.

In other words, **equivalent** code for this will be:

```
const CollectionSchema = new Schema({
  field1: [fieldSchema],
});
const fieldSchema = new Schema({
  field : { type: String, default: undefined},
});
```

As you can see, `field1` won't be undefined.

With `{ type: [String], default: () => undefined}` you just create an array of strings. That is why it works.

Answer (score 0):

*"mongoose": "^7.3.1"*

From the [Alternate declaration syntax for arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#altsyntaxarrays) documentation:

> If you create a schema with an array of objects, Mongoose will automatically convert the object to a schema for you

See the below example:

```
// @ts-nocheck
import assert from 'assert';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

const schema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
    field1: [
        {
            type: {
                type: String,
                default: undefined,
            },
        },
    ],
});
const Model1 = mongoose.model('test1', schema1);

const fieldSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: undefined,
    },
});
const schema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
    field1: [fieldSchema],
});
const Model2 = mongoose.model('test2', schema2);

const schema3 = new mongoose.Schema({
    field1: { type: [String], default: undefined },
});
const Model3 = mongoose.model('test3', schema3);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);

        // test
        assert.equal(schema1.childSchemas.length, 1);
        assert.ok(schema1.childSchemas[0]?.schema.$implicitlyCreated);
        assert.equal(schema2.childSchemas.length, 1);
        assert.ok(!schema2.childSchemas[0]?.schema.$implicitlyCreated);

        await Promise.all([Model1, Model2, Model3].map((m) => m.create({})));

        const [r1, r2, r3] = await Promise.all([Model1, Model2, Model3].map((m) => m.findOne()));
        console.log('r1: ', r1?.toObject());
        console.log('r2: ', r2?.toObject());
        console.log('r3: ', r3?.toObject());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Debug logs:

```
Mongoose: test1.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("64a2a770ed61e033b5a9736b"), field1: [], __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: test2.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("64a2a770ed61e033b5a9736c"), field1: [], __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: test3.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("64a2a770ed61e033b5a9736d"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: test1.findOne({}, {})
Mongoose: test2.findOne({}, {})
Mongoose: test3.findOne({}, {})
r1:  { _id: new ObjectId("64a2a770ed61e033b5a9736b"), field1: [], __v: 0 }
r2:  { _id: new ObjectId("64a2a770ed61e033b5a9736c"), field1: [], __v: 0 }
r3:  { _id: new ObjectId("64a2a770ed61e033b5a9736d"), __v: 0 }
```

`r3` is what you need.

Mongoose will convert the `{ type: { type: string, default: undefined } }` object to a schema and set the `schema.$implicitlyCreated` property  to `true`, see the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/95f1ec9f3c0a15c8834f1ba63912f63cc774324c/lib/schema.js#L1360):

```
const childSchema = new Schema(castFromTypeKey, childSchemaOptions);
childSchema.$implicitlyCreated = true;
return new MongooseTypes.DocumentArray(path, childSchema, obj);
```

`schema1` and `schema2` are equivalent. The schema definition means they have a `field1` path, it contains an array of [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocuments).

`schema3` means it has a `field1` path, the default value of it is `undefined`.

The `default` schema type is to set the default value for the `type` path **rather than the `field1` path.** That's why when you insert a new document, the `field1` always be an empty array.